# Yes/No : Is $F $ is uniformly continious

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following statement true or false?

> Let $ f \colon [ a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded and Riemann-integrable function. Define
>   $$ [a,b]\ni x\mapsto F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt.$$
>   Then the  function $ F$ is uniformly continious .

My attempt :  i thinks  this statement is false  Take $f(x)=-1$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0 < x \leq 1$.
It is not even continious also,,,,then we  simply  used the logics  that F will not uniformly continious

Is its true ?

Comment: If $f$ is bounded then $F$ is Lipschitz hence uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$M=\sup_{[a,b]}|f|$$
then

$$(\forall (x,y)\in [a,b]^2$$

$$x<y\implies |\int_x^yf|\le M|x-y|$$

$$\implies |F(x)-F(y)|\le M |x-y|$$

$$\implies F \text{ is UC at } [a,b]$$

Answer (score 4):

$F$ is continuous so it is uniformly continuous since its domain is compact.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is bounded by $B$, then
$|F(x)-F(y)| = | \int_x^y f(t) dt |  \le B|x-y|$, so it is Lipschitz continuous and hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Your answer need some small modification.